# Call Python script as a child process with NodeJS using Docker

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, docker

I'm new with docker and I can't run my python script from NodeJs.
It seems that the python script isn't sending any data back to javascript. Do I have to add anything to the dockerfile, for the python to run, like adding it as a new container?

NodeJs code to call python

```js
app.get('/python', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Welcome to python')
    const childProcess=require("child_process");
    const spawn = childProcess.spawn;
    const pythonProcess = spawn('python -u',['preProcessing.py', 12, 17]);

    console.log('Spawned to python')

    pythonProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());
        console.log("Child data: " + data);
    });
    pythonProcess.on('error', function () {
      console.log("Failed to start child.");
    });
    pythonProcess.on('close', function (code) {
      console.log('Child process exited with code ' + code);
    });
    pythonProcess.stdout.on('end', function () {
      console.log('Finished collecting data chunks.');
    });
    console.log('Finally')
});
```

Simple python script

```py
import sys

print(sys.argv[1])
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Docker-compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: docker-node-mongo
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - '80:3000'
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
    volumes:
    - data-volume:/data/db

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

Terminal output

```sh
docker-node-mongo | MongoDB Connected
docker-node-mongo | GET / 304 12.989 ms - -
docker-node-mongo | Welcome to python
docker-node-mongo | Spawned to python
docker-node-mongo | Finally
docker-node-mongo | Failed to start child.
docker-node-mongo | Finished collecting data chunks.
docker-node-mongo | Child process exited with code -2
docker-node-mongo | GET /python - - ms - -
```

It should print "Child data:12"

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile code? It will help us understand what your container is set up to handle.

Comment: That is a question that I have, do I need to add another container in the docker-compose to run the python script? (Docker compose added)

Comment: I don't know about your specific problem, and maybe it's not the right solution for you. But i don't think running in a child process is the way to achieve what you want to do, a second container running a python webserver (flask) would do a much better job.

Comment: Or you can use an image containing both -> https://hub.docker.com/r/nikolaik/python-nodejs/